Concatenate character macro to string literal
I have defined a character macro using #define OPT_SORT_NONE 'S'.
I'm using argp to parse command line options and I need to include this character in the documentation of another option like this (struct argp_option) { "reversed", "R", 0, 0, "Sort in descending order. This option has no effect if -" OPT_SORT_NONE " is enabled." }. However this does not work because the preprocessor cannot concatenate a string with a character.
I used stringizing to convert the char into a string but it adds quotes around it, i.e. it produces "'S'" and I only want "S".
I tried defining the macro as a string but I also need to use it in a case statement so it didn't work.
I also tried to define the macro without the quotes #define OPT_SORT_NONE S, then used stringizing to get it as a string but I can't find a way to get it as a char.
Is there a way to do the concatenation at compile time or will I need to do it at runtime?

It's not preprocessor that concatenates adjacent strings - that's the compiler side of things.  In any case, I don't believe this is possible.  Though you might be able to reorganise your code so your option is a 1-char string literal, and you access its first character when you need a char.  You might want a rethink anyway, as concatenating strings like that makes them very hard to translate.

@TobySpeight Okay thanks. I tried defining as a string and accessing the first character but as I use it in a case statement it needs to be constant so it didn't seem to work.

You’re not going to like this, but it can be done as (struct argp_option) { "reversed", "R", 0, 0, (char []) { 'S', 'o', 'r', 't', … 'i', 'f', ' ', '-', OPT_SORT_NONE, ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', 'e', 'n', 'a', 'b', 'l', 'e', 'd', '.' }.

Another option is to write a different program or a script that takes the value of OPT_SORT_NONE and produces a C string literal with it included in the string, then include the output of that program or script in the source code being compiled. There is no reason to use the built-in C preprocessor for everything; you can use any program you want for preprocessing. All you need to do is incorporate it into your build procedures.

Can OPT_SORT_NONE  be "S"? You can have a char with OPT_SORT_NONE[0]. Please share other usages of OPT_SORT_NONE.

This question is similar to: How to concatenate a character constant into a string. C. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
